# How to manage large number of rows in mysql database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Actually, We have an application which is already developed in PHP/MYSQL.
Which was running perfectly till the number of the user not more than 5K.
But now the number of users is increasing and the website's performance going down day by day. Currently, we have more than 200K records in our database. but while fetching the data and performing any other operation things are not performing well.

We want everyone's suggestion about what we need to do now

1. shall we change our server
2. shall we move from Core PHP to any other framework.
3. shall we change the database
4. or any other way to handle all those issues

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you have your indexes specified correctly on the table? I suggest you [edit] your post to show the database structure and the query your code frequently used to access the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. That depends on what kind of server you have right now.
   2.Rewriting existing app from core PHP into PHP framework may not be as easy as it looks due to the fact that it is very easy to miss some of the functionality which is (very often) missed in documentation. If you plan to keep that app, then it is worth considering for sure but...
   It also depends on which version of PHP you are using. If it is =< 5.6 then I think it will be worth to at least consider to upgrade application to > PHP7 (which is 1.8x faster according to gbksoft).
   I would recommend checking your queries as the first thing, though, since you may be able to increase their speed by correcting them and proper indexing DB columns.
   It may come out that the speed of app is not satisfying because of some code which takes long time to execute(unnecessarily) and that can be upgraded.
2. That also depends - keep in mind that if you are using MySQL and mysqli Object in PHP, it will become a nightmare. I would check if Database structure is normalized and if there is indexing and if queries are optimized (mentioned that in previous point).
3. Spend time on understanding the code to find what can be updated and improved because that may be the biggest issue of the app (It works as you wrote, but how it works is a different matter). Try upgrading version of PHP, then reduce not needed code, improve existing one, check your DB structure (if you can improve something in there). If that does not look good (everything is perfect) then consider changing server (if you are on Apache, I would recommend to go go Nginx), or even change the server hosting company that you are running on because that may be not able to handle many requests.

Many ideas are repeated, sorry for that.

To sum up: First check how to improve your existing code and how is DB doing (what can be improved), then consider changing server and then re-writing app into framework. (framework will not change too much if code is written badly so I think that can be used as the last point because it may be also the most problematic thing to do).

Answer (score 1):

200k isn't much. For example, see this page: https://wiimmfi.de/comp-stat/

There are 2 tables with >600k entries each (1 table with and one without ghosts, 1.25 Mio records total). To get the data of the page, records of both tables are selected by UNION. To support different languages and the names of drivers, vehicles, controller, countries and more, 3 inner joins and 8 left joins are used. In Admin mode (with some additional infos) the page is build in 25-28 ms. The time is measured from first PHP command (before including anything) until sending the close-body part and includes all queries needed for the page and for user management.

The websites runs on a "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1246 v3 @ 3.50GHz". Setup of the server was 2013, so it is only middle good hardware today.

What I will say: If designing tables well (members and keys; following then normalization rules: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), you can access data very fast, even if you have millions of records.

A note about frameworks: They help to create the user interface. But they don't optimize the database for you: That is always a job for a developer (team).